# fitting only the height of a label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

how to fit only the height size of label ...

i have tried this:

```
servicedes.sizeToFit()
```

but this will fit both height and width... while i just want to fit the height of it so the text will be at the first line of the label ... my label is a multi lines label ..

this is my label

[image]

and this is what i got:

[image]

the space by the blue arrow is what i don't want ...

constraints:

[image]

how to do this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: show the constraints

Comment: @Sh_Khan just updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Layout constraints aside, you should be able to use `.sizeToFit()` in a way that it only resizes the label's height by setting the width just before:

```
label.frame.width = label.frame.width
label.sizeToFit()
```

This approach won't work when using the constraints you're using right now.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- Remove 'Center X' Constraint of the label
- Add Trailing constraint(eg. 8) to the label and set relation of *Trailing Constraint* to **'greater than/equal to'**.

Adding Trailing constraint:

[image: Option at bottom right corner]

Setting Relation:

[image: Greater than relation]

Comment: am sorry but how to add the trailing constraint?

Comment: can you please check the image i just uploaded .. like this?

Comment: yours worked but the text will go greater than the image view .. and i want to limit it between the image view ..

Comment: can you check my latest uploaded images and screenshots please

Comment: Add trailing constraint with respect to the image view, right click > drag from label to image view and select trailing from options, that will limit label from going across image view. Do delete existing trailing constraint first.